# ARCore - determine phone altitude (above the ground)

Tags: android, virtual-reality, arcore

Can Android ARCore determine how **high above the ground** is the phone? I know tilt can be more or less taken from accelerometer but I'm looking for a way to precisely calculate phone position in respect to the real world.

I assume that phone altitude, tilt etc. are needed to precisely place virtual plane in respect to the real-world plain. I'm talking about cm precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARCore does not give you ground altitude directly - ARCore devices do not have depth sensors.

You would need to detect some ground plane first and measure the difference on Y-axis between phone/camera and the plane.

It certainly will not be 1cm precision though, more 10ish I guess, depending how high the phone is.

Comment: seems like an impossible task with today's hardware. Thanks.